# Create a simple module to retrieve record from database?

Tags: database, blocks

I need to create a simple module to fetch some record from database related to a node.

I have `product` nodes and users who makes `bids` in this product. Then at the time I load a `product` I need to retrieve all bids in this product to show them in a block.

I need some start guide/documentation to do it.

This is my first module attempt and this is the code I start working with: no error yet but it doesn't print out the values I need.

```
function myModule_load($node){

$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {uc_auction_bids} WHERE nid = :nid", array(':nid' => 258,));
$record = $result->fetch(); 

// print the fields/values of $record
print('<pre>');
print_r($record);
print('</pre>');
```

}

Any help for creating this simple module, please?

I just need to know which is the right function/hook where I can fetch the data from the database, and prepare the data to create the block.

Comment: Do you want to display the the bids in a block as in "a Drupal block to configure in the Admin > Structure > Blocks page" or a "a block of HTML, likely a <DIV>"?

Comment: as a Drupal block I guess.

Comment: What's wrong with loading the data from your hook_block_view() implementation (see my answer)?

Comment: I just see it. Whit that code the block should be visible at admin/structure/block right?

Comment: You also need to implement hook_block_info() as explained in the linked tutorial. Because it only returns an array on product pages (when ($node = menu_get_object()) && ($node->type === 'product') is TRUE), the block itself will not be visible on other pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Creating modules](https://drupal.org/node/1074360) tutorial covers block creation: implementation of [`hook_block_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) to declare your block, implementation of [`hook_block_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) to generate the block content, usage of [`theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) to format retrieved records and usage of [`user_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) to check user permission before giving him/her access to the information

The only missing information is the [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) function which you can use to retrieve the currently displayed node (if any).

```
function myModule_block_view($delta) {
  if (($node = menu_get_object()) && ($node->type === 'product')) {
    $results = db_query("SELECT * FROM {uc_auction_bids} WHERE nid = :nid", array(':nid' => $node->nid));
    $records = $results->fetchAllAssoc('bid');

    $content = ... // Format records here...

    return array(
      'subject' => t('Bids'),
      'content' => $content
    );
  }
}
```

A more complex solution, but a flexier one, would be to expose the `uc_auction_bids` table to views using a [`hook_views_data()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7) implementation. You could then create a block display using a contextual filter to retrieve the current node ID.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do this with the Views module. Or is the Bid Table not something made with Drupal?

Just create a block (in views) and choose the data you would like to show for a particular node. Then add a "Contextual filter" with the node ID you're currently viewing.

Comment: I tried but views doesn't show the field `bids` for the product content type. It only shows thes fields: `last bid` , `higher bid` and `bid counts`. So, there's no way to show all bids in a given product.

Comment: That is a problem of the Ubercat Auction module, which doesn't include the necessary code to expose the database field you are interested to, in its Views-integration code.